# How to get rid of the warning message

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I updated ruby gems to 1.13.7 by `gem update --system`. After that, I get a deprecated warning message:

> Using the :class locator to locate multiple classes with a String value is deprecated; use an Array instead

I used `@browser.div(class: 'abcbbbb')` class locator in my scripts. I do not know how to change this to avoid the warning message. Please share the view on this issue.

Comment: For your information, an English sentence starts with a capital letter, and ends with a period.

Comment: Must be the warning is about another instance of class locator

Answer (score 6):

> Using the :class locator to locate multiple classes with a String value is deprecated; use an Array instead

Watir shows [the above warning](https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/v6.6.0/lib/watir/locators/element/selector_builder/xpath.rb#L51-L53) if your class name contains a space, e.g.

```
@browser.div(class: 'foo bar')
```

Because these are in fact two classes, `foo` and `bar`. You are therefore supposed to pass an array:

```
@browser.div(class: ['foo', 'bar'])
```

or via Ruby's [`%w`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings) shortcut:

```
@browser.div(class: %w(foo bar))
```